# Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in MAMP

Tags: php, com, mamp

I am facing this issue

> Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ctor/abc.php on line 10

the abc.php is as follows

```
<?php
ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 300);

$filename = "abc.xlsx";

$sheet1 = 4;

$arr=array(1=>'a','b','c','d');

$excel_app = new COM("Excel.application") or Die ("Did not connect");

?>
```

please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

COM is [available on Windows only.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php)

Deducting from the "MAMP" in your path, you seem to be on an Apple Machine. Mac OS is Unix based.

Comment: So how to run on MAC OS X (MAMP) i really need to make a php web application that imports and exports excel.... any suggestions any third party file/com available to run it on mac?

Comment: @user there are Excel readers/writers available that don't need COM, eg. http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/